# PHP Show results else nothing to display

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this script here that shows a list of results.  How to do l say "No results" if no results are found.  I believe it's the else statement but couldn't quiet get it to work.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emailquotes order by id desc") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo "<tr height='25px' valign='center'>";
    echo '<td valign="middle"><p><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="../../Images/Icons/table-delete.png"/></a></p></td>';
    echo '<td><p>' . $row['ssp'] . '</p></td>';
    echo '<td><p>' . $row['ssp'] . '@someonewhere.com</p></td>';
    echo '<td><p>' . $row['surname'] . '</p></td>';
    echo '<td><p>Car</p></td>';
    echo '<td><p><a href="add-prices.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Show Prices</a></p></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Before while loop, use mysql_num_rows($result) in if like this: if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {while()....} else { //no result}

Comment: get the number of rows return from the query, if greater than zero, print, else no results found

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) function:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count > 0) {
  // loop rows
} else {
  // no result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your while loop in a if-statement and check if there is any results before running the loop. Then you echo "No results" in the else.

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be like this:

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emailquotes order by id desc") 
or die(mysql_error());
if( mysql_num_rows($result)) { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

      echo "<tr height='25px' valign='center'>";
      echo '<td valign="middle"><p><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img       
         src="../../Images/Icons/table-delete.png"/></a></p></td>';
     echo '<td><p>' . $row['ssp'] . '</p></td>';
     echo '<td><p>' . $row['ssp'] . '@someonewhere.com</p></td>';
     echo '<td><p>' . $row['surname'] . '</p></td>';
     echo '<td><p>Car</p></td>';
     echo '<td><p><a href="add-prices.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Show Prices</a></p></td>';
     echo "</tr>"; 
   } 
}
else {
  echo "No Result";
}
?>
```